# Rank of matrix product formulation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $n\times n$ square matrices $A,B$.

We know $rank(AB)\leq\min(rank(A),rank(B))$.

When is $rank(AB)=\min(rank(A),rank(B))$?

We know $rank(A+B)\leq rank(A)+rank(B)$.

When is $rank(A+B)=rank(A)+rank(B)$?

Comment: the equality occurs when $\ker(A) \subset image(B).$

Answer (score 0):

For a reference see here the article [Equalities and Inequalities for ranks of matrices](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/PUB/Doutorado/2012-Biller/Marsaglia1974.pdf) by Marsaglia and Styan (1973). Both of the above rank inequalities are discussed, among many others, and conditions for equality are formulated, e.g., see Corollary 8.1. and Corollary 6.1. ff.